# Sample mean and sample covariance canonical forms

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, data-analysis, canonical-transformation

Let $(x_1, x_2,\dotsc, x_n)$ be a sequence of vectors: ($\forall i=1,\dots,n$)
\begin{pmatrix}
   x_i^1  \\
   x_i^2\\
   \vdots\\
   x_i^m
\end{pmatrix}

In statistics, one often has to compute the **sample mean** vector:
 $$X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

and the **sample covariance** (or **variance-covariance**) matrix:
$$\mathbb{V} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - X)(x_i - X)^T$$
where $x^T$ is the transpose of $x$.

My questions are:

1. what **canonical** form of information would I suggest
   to represent the sequence $(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n)$ in order to compute the sample mean vector and the sample covariance matrix?
2. How can I verify that all the desirable properties of canonical information are satisfied: **Existence and Uniqueness**, **Completeness**, **Elementary**, **Empty**, **Combination**, **Update**, and **Compactness and Efficiency**.
3. What are the **minimum number** of observations $n$ for which $X$ and $\mathbb{V}$ are defined?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: @PackSciences Unfortunately, I don't even have an idea of how to start this task. Could you help me, please?